# How to check in aspxgridview if a record is generated from another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a grid, that contains 6 fields same as its table, i.e. transaction table contains 6 fields. This grid contains:

```
Transactionid
Name
Date
Transactiontype
amount
action
```

Transaction type can be sale, if transaction is sale,authorize if its authorize, refund if its refund, postauthorize if its capture and void if transaction is void. These refund,void and capture resides in action field of the grid, if transaction type is sale then you can do a refund, so in the corresponding action field you'll get refund action.Now after you do a refund or capture or void another record is inserted into database with a new transaction id.

Now my question is when im checking for this newly inserted record i can not get this refund transaction is done from which sale transaction. If someone do a partial refund, then i have to calculate how much amount is remaining. I cannot add anymore fields to my table, is it possible that way ?

```
Transaction ID       Name   Trans Date  Type       Amount          Action
qwee1321312          aa bb  03/21/2012  Sale       $14.00      Refund  
adsd231233           aa bb  03/26/2012  Sale       $50.00      Refund  
12312dda             aa bb  03/26/2012  Authorize  $100.00    Capture   Void
                     aa bb  03/26/2012   Void      $100.00
```

Action field is to perform refund,capture or void transction. Whenever you do void or refund or capture a new row created.Now how to get and remove action field of 3rd row from where 4th row is created.
Im checking on htmlrowcreated event

```
 if (type == "Sale")
                {
                    //Checks Amount for sale transaction
                    amount = Convert.ToDecimal(CheckTransaction(Convert.ToInt64(tid), (int)Enums.TransactionType.Refund));
                    if (amount > 0)
                    {
                        lnkaction.Text = "Refund";
                        lnkaction.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return RefundPopup('" + tid + "','" + Refund1.lblClientID + "','" + amount + "','Refund Sale');");
                    }
                }
                else if (type == "Authorize")
                {
                    //Checks Amount for authorization transaction
                    amount = Convert.ToDecimal(CheckTransaction(Convert.ToInt64(tid), (int)Enums.TransactionType.PostAuthorize));
                    if (amount > 0)
                    {
                        lnkaction.Text = "Capture";
                        lnkaction.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:return RefundPopup('" + tid + "','" + Refund1.lblClientID + "','" + amount + "','Capture Sale');");
                        lnkvoid.Text = "Void";
                    }
                }
```

But its not working, after i do a refund or void.

Comment: I've read your question multiple times and cannot work out what you are asking or how it relates to an AspxGridView. You may want to revise the question and make it clearer.

Comment: Please describe it properly i can't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Please check my question, ive edited it.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve but....

> **What I think you are trying to do.**
>
> Your example has 3 rows?
>
> The user clicks "Void" on row 3?
>
> This then creates the 4th row?
>
> You now wish to remove the "Capture" and "Void" buttons from row 3?

You should mark the row as refunded in some way e.g Set the type to "Refunded" or "Voided" and then hide the buttons for this type using their Visible property

Comment: No no, not remove the row i want to remove action field only.

Comment: then set the link objects visible property to false. i.e lnkvoid.Visible=False;

Comment: Ok, how to do same thing for refund? Please check my question, you will see two refundable records, if i click on 2nd one, it will create a new record of refund. Now how can i know that its 2nd record i ve refunded.

Comment: You seem to be assuming I can tell what your code is doing. I cannot tell from such a small snippet. You should work out exactly what your question is and then ask it in the clearest way possible.  I can tell English is not your first language but nobody will help you if they do not understand your question..

Comment: You say it "is not working". You need to define what you mean by this. What are you trying to achieve? What does happen and what do you want to happen?

Comment: Very sorry for that, i was so trying to make the question easier. But this thing is really messy, thats why im having difficulties to make you guys understand my question. So, the action field here is generated in the code snippet, when type =sale action field will contain refund action. And when i click on refund action it will insert another record to the db, and it also affects my action field to become nothing, because i ve already done refund action on that particular row right ?

Comment: Now when i have two records of type "sale", then after doing a refund on 2nd record i want to remove the action field of that record, make sense right? I cant seem to do that....

Comment: I have amended my answer above